# Trouble creating a Layout for a Panel in C#

Tags: c#, layout, layout-manager

I want to create a Layout Manager which divides the panel into cells and a component can be added to the panel specifying the cell (row, column). The cells width and height should be updated upon re-sizing the panel (this is the problem, it does not re-size cells' size). The classes by themselves work, but when resizing it does not update the cells size, it does not even seem to be calling `LayoutManager::SetBounds(int, int)`. The reason why I am creating a separate class is because I am gonna use that same Layout Manager for other containers, for instance a `GroupBox`. Here its is my code

```
public class Insets
{
    public int bottom = 0;
    public int top = 0;
    public int left = 0;
    public int right = 0;

    public Insets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
        this.bottom = bottom;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

/*
*  LayoutManager class
*/

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;



public class LayoutManager
{
    public enum Constraints{
        HORIZONTAL,
        VERTICAL,
        NONE
    };

    public Insets insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    public Constraints fill = Constraints.NONE;
    public Panel container = null;
    public int cellheight = 1;
    public int cellwidth = 1;

    private List <int> indices = new List <int>();
    private int columns = 1;
    private int rows = 1;
    private int dh = 0;
    private int dw = 0;

    public LayoutManager(){
    }
    private int Index2DTo1D(int row, int column){
        return (column + (row * columns));
    }
    private int Index1DToRow2D(int index){
        return index / columns;
    }
    private int Index1DToColumn2D(int index){
        return index / rows;
    }
    private void SetGridMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
        if (rows >= this.rows){
            this.rows = rows + 1;
        }
        if (columns >= this.columns){
            this.columns = columns + 1;
        }
    }
    public void RepaintChildrenComponents() {
        if(container != null){
            foreach(Control control in container.Controls){
                ((CheckBox)control).Text = container.Width.ToString();
            }       
        }
    }
    public void SetBounds(int width, int height) {
        SetCellsDimensions(width, height);
        RepaintChildrenComponents();
    }
    public void SetCellsDimensions(int width, int height){
        this.dw = width / columns;
        this.dh = height / rows;
    }
    public void SetContainer(ref Panel container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public Point GetChildComponentXY(int x, int y){
        if(x >= 0 && y >= 0){
            return new Point((x * dw) + insets.right, (y * dh) + insets.top);
        }
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("");
    }
    public Size GetComputedComponentSize(){
        return new Size((cellwidth * dw) - (insets.left + insets.right),
                        (cellheight * dh) - (insets.top + insets.bottom));            
    }
    public void AddComponent(Control control, Point location, LayoutManager.Constraints fill){
        if(container != null && control != null){
            indices.Insert(container.Controls.Count, Index2DTo1D(location.X, location.Y));
            container.Controls.Add(SetChildComponentBounds(control, location));
            SetGridMatrix(location.X, location.Y);
            SetCellsDimensions(container.Width, container.Height);
        }else{
            throw new NullReferenceException("");
        }
    }
    protected Control SetChildComponentBounds(Control control, Point location) {
        control.Location = GetChildComponentXY(location.X, location.Y);
        control.Size = GetComputedComponentSize();
        return control;
    }
    public void AddComponent(Control control, Point location){
        AddComponent(control, location, LayoutManager.Constraints.NONE);
    }
}

/*
*
* JPanel class
*/


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


class JPanel : Panel
{
    private LayoutManager layman;

    public JPanel(){
        layman = new JComponent.LayoutManager();

        Panel container = this;
        layman.SetContainer(ref container);


        string[] elems = { "Multiplication", "Division", "Addition", "Subtraction"};
        int e = 0;

        this.Size = new Size(300, 125);

        foreach(string str in elems){

            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
            box.Text = str;
            layman.AddComponent(box, new Point(0, e++));
            //this.Controls.Add(box);
        }

    }
    public JPanel(LayoutManager layman) {
        LayoutManager = layman;
    }

    protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified){
        if(layman != null){
            layman.SetBounds(width, height);
        }
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
    }
    public LayoutManager LayoutManager{
        set{
            layman = value;
        }
        get{
            return layman;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom datagrid (UserControl/OwnerDraw)?

Comment: I agree with the above poster this seems to me to be exactly what a Grid does. If you are looking to add Grid functionality to other controls why not just add the Grid to the controls children, and have it set up how ever you want. You can easily create a method which would automatically do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the TableLayoutPanel class. I think this control is exactly doing what you are trying to achieve. The TableLayoutPanel allows you to define rows / columns in the forms editor and programatically, place control inside the cells, merge rows / columns, autosize the panel according to the content or autosize the content according to the panel size.

Here's a very interesting documentation about how layouting works in windows forms:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:nePz-uaPReYJ:www.windowsclient.net/samples/go%2520to%2520market/layout/layoutgtm.doc+Whidbey+Layout+tablelayoutpanel&hl=de&gl=de&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShlobh-RfSTegC1NuOc72m0vRPu6RsF3USTSPnSasU-9qSklTbJzclRol6Nxg5sxEUXZOWYZwgrSdZdAjJ5EXhCft7qj5jBr4-kkkX6380-0itVaHkG-TAvK4KvNtDymEFlUXM6&sig=AHIEtbTnyasKOG5tuZwub59LBw8UeZL8Lg

Unfortunatelly i could only find the documentation by the google search cache. The original link seems to be removed.